# Magento 1.9: How to get Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price of product?

Tags: magento-1.9

i tried this code but it empty.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
            foreach($collection as $product){
                print_r($product->getmsrp());
            }exit;
```

Comment: Try $product->getMsrp();

Comment: It not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try this way.

I have tested it's working fine.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($collection as $product) {
    $productData = $product->getData();
    $msrpPrice = $productData['msrp'];
    echo $msrpPrice;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. i got it.

Comment: Thank for mark as a right answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see if it is working

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($collection as $product){
    echo $product->getMsrp();
}
```

if you custom attribute code is `msrp` then `getMsrp()` should work.

If you still not getting your result then you need to set "**use in product listing**" option from manage attributes

> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

Edit your attribute. In **Storefront Properties** tab select **Used in Product Listing** to "**Yes**"

then check again after reindex

Comment: i tried this code but it still not working

Comment: did you add this code? `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');`

Comment: what is the attribute code?

Comment: i got it. thank all <3